# Accessing elements of Office clipboard programmatically

Tags: winapi, excel, vsto, clipboard, vba

As Office clipboard is different from System (windows) clipboard in a way that it can contain multiple items.

Is it possible to iterate over the elements of office clipboard programmatically?

Thanks.

Shakti

Comment: Office has an extensive automation model, have you Googled it?

Comment: I googled it. but no success. :(

Comment: @Shaktisaxena did you ever come up with a solution here? I have a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API or documentation for the Office Clipboard.

Here's an article from 2010 that explores [accessing MSO.dll directly](http://www.benf.org/excel/officeclip/) to use the Office Clipboard.

I have not tested the code myself.

Comment: That's me ;)  That particular bit of code works by using hardcoded non documented entry points to MSO.dll - i.e. it's (as I mention in the comments) rather brittle, and not liable to withstand an office patch.

Comment: As with most (useful) things Office, that's as good as we're gonna get!

Comment: @lab27 I know this maybe alot to ask, but could you do a follow up post on your blog to explain how you found the clearClipboard and getClipboardCount functions? I asked on stackoverflow to see if anyone knew how it was you came up with the address per version of office but no response so far. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37971724/how-to-get-stable-address-from-a-dll