# How to get stable Address from a dll?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, reverse-engineering

A DLL has a set of exported functions that other applications can call. Typically to call these functions you either have a function name or an ordinal number.

In `MSO.dll`, most of the exported entry points to the DLL don't have names, so I can't call the function I want pragmatically by normal means.

Upon a bit of Google searching I ran into a blogger that claims to have found stable addresses (addresses that don't change) to the very function I want to call.

The issue with these addresses is that they can't be counted on to be the same from one release of Office to another, or even from one update to the next. So I need to find out how Lee Benfield found these stable addresses in `MSO.dll` when he wrote his [blog post](http://www.benf.org/excel/officeclip/). You can find the source code on his blog.

The portion of Lee's code I am trying to understand:

[image]

Here is some code I wrote to find these addresses:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    HMODULE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary("C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office 15\\root\\vfs\\ProgramFilesCommonX86\\Microsoft Shared\\OFFICE15\\mso.dll");

    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS header = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((char *)hGetProcIDDLL + ((PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)hGetProcIDDLL)->e_lfanew);
    PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY exports = (PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY)((char *)hGetProcIDDLL + header->
        OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT].VirtualAddress);

    char** names = (char**)((int)hGetProcIDDLL + exports->AddressOfNames);
    std::cout << "Total # of functions: " << exports->NumberOfFunctions << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Total # of named functions: " << exports->NumberOfNames << std::endl;

    std::map<uintptr_t, char*> addressToName;

    for (uint16_t i = 0; i < exports->NumberOfNames; i++)
    {
        char* name = (char*)hGetProcIDDLL + (int)names[i];
        void* fn = GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, name);
        addressToName[(uintptr_t)fn] = name;
        //std::cout << "Export: Name: " << name << " Address: " << fn << "\n";

    }

    for (uint16_t i = 1; i < exports->NumberOfFunctions; i++)
    {
        void* fn = GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(i));
        std::map<uintptr_t, char*>::iterator it;
        it = addressToName.find((uintptr_t)fn);
        std::cout << "oridinal #: " << i << " address: " << fn << " Name: " << (it != addressToName.end() ? it->second : "N\\A") << "\n";
    }

    // Free the DLL module.
    if (!FreeLibrary(hGetProcIDDLL))
    {
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It essentially does the same thing as [Dumpbin.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c.aspx) [/Export](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30e78zd0.aspx), but also prints out the `procAddress`, name, and ordinal value. Below you can see a picture of a diff of two runs. The two byte of the higher order word are stable.

[image: diff example]

see [bin dump 1](http://pastebin.com/A5BsLdJK) and [bin dump 2](http://pastebin.com/5irDX5Ec).

My question has a few parts:

1. what makes the higher order word stable and the lower order word vary?
2. how do I get the stable addresses that Lee found in the MSO.dll?
3. how do I find out which one is the `clearclipboard` and `getClipboardCount` function should I find a stable address?

Comment: Someone *"found stable addresses in MSO.dll"* - I have no idea, what that is supposed to mean.

Comment: Ok let me give more background info, thanks for catching this ambiguity.

Comment: @IInspectable is this better?

Comment: *"most of the exported entry points to the dll don't have names so I can't call the function I want pragmatically by normal means"* - Why? You can pass an ordinal to [GetProcAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212.aspx) as well. No name required. *"So I need to find out how Lee Benfield found these stable addresses in MSO.dll"* - Why? What are you going to do with that information?

Comment: @IInspectable The last version of office his project supports is 2007. I'd like to update it for 2010-16

Comment: you are right I can pass an ordinal (in fact that is what I am doing to generate the two dump file), but I'm not sure if the ordinals are stable from one release of office to another. so I don't know if I am calling the same function he does mention the following on the ordinals "Ordinals 2959 and 1560 in mso.dll look like they might be useful for a more dependable office clipboard api, however there's other stuff going on which make them less useful (memmoves etc)."

Comment: Why would you expect to be able to call an undocumented private interface? Why are you hacking like this?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If there was a nice API to call into the office clipboard I would use it in a heartbeat. The primary reason that it is an undocumented interface is forcing me down this road. I expect to be able to call it the same way the office suite of application call these functions. They have been around since office 2000 https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/221190 but never got an API in the last 16 years. I doubt much has changed in the calling convention. Probably the only real changes are a result of the compiler moving things around.

Comment: If you want to build your program on top of undocumented private reverse engineered interfaces that's on you. But you should not expect any stability. If MS don't want to provide you an API, that is entirely their prerogative.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I understand that, I'm not asking or expecting MS to provide and API. I totally get this is not the desired way to go about solving problems. I'm not exploiting a security vulnerability and my intent is not malicious so I doubt MS would even care. I read an interesting blog post and wanted to replicate the results for newer versions of office.

Comment: @user1881587: since you are relying on a private undocumented API, you are responsible for validating that API on every new release and make adjustments to your code accordingly. There is no guarantee that exported ordinals will not change from one release to the next.  Public DLL exports should be exported by name to avoid this problem.

Comment: "I doubt MS would even care." We care because it means that the user installs the new version of Office and your app stops working. The user then says "The new version of Office doesn't work. It makes this app crash. I rely on this app for my day-to-day work. This is a critical bug in Office."

Comment: I never thought this question would get the attention of @RaymondChen. Thank you for your blog! While you're here could I ask for an office clipboard API? In all seriousness though if MS does not provide the functionality we as app developers need, are we suppose to just give up?

Comment: The clipboard already has its own set of API functions. Why do you need anything from Office?

Comment: @MarkRansom I can't get into to much of the details but my app already hooks the windows clipboard  and drag and drop functions. So I am aware of them and am using them. That said there remains a hole in my implementation that requires a bit further digging. I wish I could be a bit less ambiguous here, but I can't.

Comment: Not only are the addresses of the functions subject to change, but the function signatures or behaviors could change as well. Since they're not publicly exposed, Microsoft could change things on a whim - they only have to coordinate the changes within their own team.I wish I could be more helpful here, but I can't.

Comment: I am aware Microsoft can change the functions signatures at any time. that the compiler can change the ordinal values and addresses especially as new patch come in. It is not helpful to continue the line of discussion that I should not do this. I fully realize the support criteria goes up by doing so and that any update or service pack could be a breaking change. Hopefully we can move past all the reasons not to do this and instead come up with why this is a) no longer possible  or b) how it was Lee Benfield did it in the first place.

Comment: Sending feature requests to me doesn't really accomplish much.

Comment: The reason I can't help you is that I've never tried to do anything so ill-advised, so I don't have any experience in this area. Giving us more information about what you're trying to accomplish, rather than how you want to do it, would enable an entirely different discussion that would be more productive. Good luck to you.

Comment: @RaymondChen thanks for taking the time to look at my question. I meant the feature request as a joke, I hope you did not take any offense.

Comment: @MarkRansom I don't mean to do anything ill advised here. I'll try and get more clarification as to what I can and can't talk about and maybe do another post to hopefully get the ball rolling.  I appreciate the outreach everyone, Thanks so much to you all for taking the time!

Answer (score 0):

1.) "what makes the higher order word stable and the lower order word vary?" - at first this is not true at all. if take CONCRETE binary mso.dll - every func have some RVA (relative VA from module base). but if you take any another mso.dll build - with almost 100% posibility - you got another RVA for functions. you looking for VA - absolute address. but VA = ImageBase + RVA, where ImageBase - address(HMODULE) at which your mso.dll is loaded. however it call all time load at different addreses (ASLR) - so VA will be not stable at all. RVA will be stable only while you use same mso.dll version (in another versions and RVA will be another)

2.) how do I get the stable addresses that Lee found in the MSO.dll? - Lee nothing found. this, as i describe, mistake question at all. if function exported - you can got in address by name or ordinal (ordinal may be also not stable, but this is very depended from dll). also possible, if you have pdb file, get public symbol address (RVA), from pdb by name(even for not exported symbols)

3)how do I find out which one is the clearclipboard and getClipboardCount function should I find a stable address? - again - no any "stable address" exist. only exports or symbols in pdb